# node.js V0.10.1 npm install grunt-contrib in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

windowsXP node.js V0.10.1 download smi package from offical site, I want to run code check from github https://github.com/raDiesle/backbone.js-jquerymobile-boilerplate-template#general

Quick start say:

```
Download and install node.js for your os system and run in your project folder:
npm install -g grunt ( installs grunt command line tool)
npm install -g bbb ( is a grunt addon, which offers backbone templates and task collections like grunt-contrib)
npm install grunt-contrib ( needed to install not global, because you'll need the newest version)
```

grunt and bbb install success,but grunt-contrib fail

the debug is so long ,copy from end

```
    33742 verbose read json E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits\package.json
33743 silly lockFile 173eb7fd-dules-glob-node-modules-inherits E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits
33744 silly lockFile 173eb7fd-dules-glob-node-modules-inherits E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits
33745 silly lockFile abd1689b-cache-inherits-1-0-0-package-tgz C:\Documents and Settings\jinkai\Application Data\npm-cache\inherits\1.0.0\package.tgz
33746 silly lockFile abd1689b-cache-inherits-1-0-0-package-tgz C:\Documents and Settings\jinkai\Application Data\npm-cache\inherits\1.0.0\package.tgz
33747 info preinstall inherits@1.0.0
33748 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits\package.json
33749 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
33750 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits\package.json
33751 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
33752 silly resolved []
33753 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits
33754 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits
33755 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inherits\package.json
33756 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33756 verbose linkStuff   false,
33756 verbose linkStuff   false,
33756 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jshint\\node_modules\\jshint\\node_modules\\cli\\node_modules\\glob\\node_modules' ]
33757 info linkStuff inherits@1.0.0
33758 verbose linkBins inherits@1.0.0
33759 verbose linkMans inherits@1.0.0
33760 verbose rebuildBundles inherits@1.0.0
33761 info install inherits@1.0.0
33762 info postinstall inherits@1.0.0
33763 verbose read json E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json
33764 silly lockFile af029bc7-es-glob-node-modules-graceful-fs E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs
33765 silly lockFile af029bc7-es-glob-node-modules-graceful-fs E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs
33766 silly lockFile b89c3973-he-graceful-fs-1-2-0-package-tgz C:\Documents and Settings\jinkai\Application Data\npm-cache\graceful-fs\1.2.0\package.tgz
33767 silly lockFile b89c3973-he-graceful-fs-1-2-0-package-tgz C:\Documents and Settings\jinkai\Application Data\npm-cache\graceful-fs\1.2.0\package.tgz
33768 info preinstall graceful-fs@1.2.0
33769 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json
33770 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
33771 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json
33772 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
33773 silly resolved []
33774 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs
33775 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs
33776 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\graceful-fs\package.json
33777 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33777 verbose linkStuff   false,
33777 verbose linkStuff   false,
33777 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jshint\\node_modules\\jshint\\node_modules\\cli\\node_modules\\glob\\node_modules' ]
33778 info linkStuff graceful-fs@1.2.0
33779 verbose linkBins graceful-fs@1.2.0
33780 verbose linkMans graceful-fs@1.2.0
33781 verbose rebuildBundles graceful-fs@1.2.0
33782 info install graceful-fs@1.2.0
33783 info postinstall graceful-fs@1.2.0
33784 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob
33785 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob
33786 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\node_modules\glob\package.json
33787 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33787 verbose linkStuff   false,
33787 verbose linkStuff   false,
33787 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jshint\\node_modules\\jshint\\node_modules\\cli\\node_modules' ]
33788 info linkStuff glob@3.1.21
33789 verbose linkBins glob@3.1.21
33790 verbose linkMans glob@3.1.21
33791 verbose rebuildBundles glob@3.1.21
33792 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'graceful-fs', 'inherits' ]
33793 info install glob@3.1.21
33794 info postinstall glob@3.1.21
33795 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli
33796 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli
33797 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\node_modules\cli\package.json
33798 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33798 verbose linkStuff   false,
33798 verbose linkStuff   false,
33798 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jshint\\node_modules\\jshint\\node_modules' ]
33799 info linkStuff cli@0.4.3
33800 verbose linkBins cli@0.4.3
33801 verbose linkMans cli@0.4.3
33802 verbose rebuildBundles cli@0.4.3
33803 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'glob' ]
33804 info install cli@0.4.3
33805 info postinstall cli@0.4.3
33806 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint
33807 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint
33808 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\package.json
33809 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33809 verbose linkStuff   false,
33809 verbose linkStuff   false,
33809 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jshint\\node_modules' ]
33810 info linkStuff jshint@1.0.0
33811 verbose linkBins jshint@1.0.0
33812 verbose link bins [ { jshint: './bin/jshint' },
33812 verbose link bins   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-jshint\\node_modules\\.bin',
33812 verbose link bins   false ]
33813 verbose linkMans jshint@1.0.0
33814 verbose rebuildBundles jshint@1.0.0
33815 info E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint unbuild
33816 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\jshint\package.json
33817 info preuninstall jshint@1.0.0
33818 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
33818 verbose rebuildBundles   'cli',
33818 verbose rebuildBundles   'esprima',
33818 verbose rebuildBundles   'minimatch',
33818 verbose rebuildBundles   'peakle',
33818 verbose rebuildBundles   'shelljs',
33818 verbose rebuildBundles   'underscore' ]
33819 info uninstall jshint@1.0.0
33820 verbose false,E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules,E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules unbuild jshint@1.0.0
33821 verbose E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\node_modules\.bin,[object Object] binRoot
33822 info postuninstall jshint@1.0.0
33823 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint
33824 info E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint unbuild
33825 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json
33826 info preuninstall grunt-contrib-jshint@0.2.0
33827 info uninstall grunt-contrib-jshint@0.2.0
33828 verbose false,E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules,E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules unbuild grunt-contrib-jshint@0.2.0
33829 info postuninstall grunt-contrib-jshint@0.2.0
33830 info postinstall phantomjs@1.8.2-2
33831 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs
33832 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs
33833 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\package.json
33834 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33834 verbose linkStuff   false,
33834 verbose linkStuff   false,
33834 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib-qunit\\node_modules' ]
33835 info linkStuff grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
33836 verbose linkBins grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
33837 verbose linkMans grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
33838 verbose rebuildBundles grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
33839 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'phantomjs' ]
33840 info install grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
33841 info postinstall grunt-lib-phantomjs@0.2.0
33842 verbose about to build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit
33843 info build E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit
33844 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\package.json
33845 verbose linkStuff [ false,
33845 verbose linkStuff   false,
33845 verbose linkStuff   false,
33845 verbose linkStuff   'E:\\workspace2\\backbone\\node_modules\\grunt-contrib\\node_modules' ]
33846 info linkStuff grunt-contrib-qunit@0.2.0
33847 verbose linkBins grunt-contrib-qunit@0.2.0
33848 verbose linkMans grunt-contrib-qunit@0.2.0
33849 verbose rebuildBundles grunt-contrib-qunit@0.2.0
33850 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'grunt-lib-phantomjs' ]
33851 info install grunt-contrib-qunit@0.2.0
33852 info postinstall grunt-contrib-qunit@0.2.0
33853 verbose read json E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\package.json
33854 verbose from cache E:\workspace2\backbone\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\package.json
33855 verbose cache add [ 'grunt@~0.4.0', null ]
33856 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="grunt@~0.4.0" args=["grunt@~0.4.0",null]
33857 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   host: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   port: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   search: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   query: null,
33857 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'grunt@~0.4.0',
33857 verbose parsed url   path: 'grunt@~0.4.0',
33857 verbose parsed url   href: 'grunt@~0.4.0' }
33858 verbose cache add name="grunt" spec="~0.4.0" args=["grunt","~0.4.0"]
33859 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   host: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   port: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   search: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   query: null,
33859 verbose parsed url   pathname: '~0.4.0',
33859 verbose parsed url   path: '~0.4.0',
33859 verbose parsed url   href: '~0.4.0' }
33860 verbose addNamed [ 'grunt', '~0.4.0' ]
33861 verbose addNamed [ null, '>=0.4.0- <0.5.0-' ]
33862 silly lockFile cba964e3-grunt-0-4-0 grunt@~0.4.0
33863 verbose lock grunt@~0.4.0 C:\Documents and Settings\jinkai\Application Data\npm-cache\cba964e3-grunt-0-4-0.lock
33864 silly addNameRange { name: 'grunt', range: '>=0.4.0- <0.5.0-', hasData: false }
33865 verbose url raw grunt
33866 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './grunt' ]
33867 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
33868 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 09:34:05
33869 verbose etag "9W6PIJKXOXJNJCW9NGQ0Z66JS"
33870 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt
33871 error phantomjs@0.2.6 install: `node install.js`
33871 error `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 8
33872 error Failed at the phantomjs@0.2.6 install script.
33872 error This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
33872 error not with npm itself.
33872 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
33872 error     node install.js
33872 error You can get their info via:
33872 error     npm owner ls phantomjs
33872 error There is likely additional logging output above.
33873 error System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
33874 error command "D:\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "grunt-contrib"
33875 error cwd E:\workspace2\backbone
33876 error node -v v0.10.1
33877 error npm -v 1.2.15
33878 error code ELIFECYCLE
33879 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

who can tell me how to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue can be tracked down to the following lines:

```
33871 error phantomjs@0.2.6 install: `node install.js`
33871 error `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 8
33872 error Failed at the phantomjs@0.2.6 install script.
33872 error This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
33872 error not with npm itself.
```

So obviously there's a problem.

Can you install phantomjs@0.2.6 manually without further ado?

PS: Did you run `npm -g` as an administrator?

Comment: i have try to run npm -g and install phantomjs@0.2.6 first but fail again

Comment: Did you run it as an administrator?

Comment: npm -g is set global paramter, how to run it as administrator @Golo Roden

Comment: Simply open up a console with administrative privileges. See http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx for details.

Comment: i use windowsXP not win7 ,and open nodejs command prompt directly ,so maybe not the privilege problem